# node js mysql accessing javascript object

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am querying a db from Node.JS  I am trying to get access to the content of the FileContent field in CodeFile, it returns a Javascript object: result.

```
jsUpdateCon.query('SELECT FileContent FROM codeFile WHERE ID = ?',[msg[1]], function(err, result){
if (err) throw err;
console.log('Data received from DB:\n');
    console.log(result);
});
```

console output: `[ RowDataPacket { FileContent: 'someContent' } ]`

if I try `console.log(result.RowDataPacket);` I get

console output: `undefined`

if I try `console.log(result.RowDataPacket.FileContent);`

The entire node crashes with

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'FileContent' of undefined`

my ultimate goal would be to get

console output: `someContent` when using console.log(result.something.something)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the `result` is an array, try to access it like this:

```
console.log(result[0].FileContent)
```